# Why is my task bar always displayed

Tags: windows-7, taskbar, user-interface

I have "lock the task bar" unset and the task bar used to dissapear. It now appears to be always displayed. It is particularly annoying because if you take a window to the top of the screen it displays the bottomn of the window under the taskbar.

This is similar to the following, but in my case it appears to be always in the display position.
[Why does my Windows task bar pop up and down](https://superuser.com/questions/284571/why-does-my-windows-task-bar-pop-up-and-down).

**Update** -

I can get it back to normal behavior by unsetting and then reselecting properties > autohide. But it doesnt stay that way for long :-(

Comment: I suspect a third party addin

Comment: I have the same problem with Windows 7 64-bit.  The taskbar is very quirky.  The irritating part is that the bottom of windows will nest underneath the task bar.  I doubt it's a third-party addin, since it's an OS issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [forum thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-desktop/windows-7-desktop-and-personalization-auto-hide/06e52c6f-ec8e-4397-b2d3-609698909279) has a number of solutions which may help.  A couple of them are listed below:

1. Kill all `explorer.exe` processes and restart `explorer.exe` from the Task Manager.
2. Turn off the network icon in the icon notification area (go to taskbar and choose customize for the show hidden icons, then choose turn system icons off "lower left of screen" and then turn off network icon.)

Comment: Further investigation - problem seems related to the network icon. It occurs when I not on a network. But hiding the network icon doesn't seem to cure the problem.  It is a cunning plot to stop me working on the train etc.